# Will an edit to a community wiki bump the question?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki, bumping

I've had no luck finding an answer to the title question, sad to say. Here, briefly, is the situation. I happened to look at an answer I gave eighteen months ago and discovered that I had written '-' where I should have written '+'. The question (and answers) have a community wiki designation. I'm uncomfortable bumping an ancient question, however good it is, to the first page for such a minor edit. Will that happen, or can I do the edit with impunity?

Answer (score 9):

I am pretty certain that any edit to any question or answer (regardless of whether it is Community Wiki or not) will bump the associated question.  The [MSE bumping faq](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/48579/214632) gives no indication that Community Wiki posts are treated any differently.  (And because the requirements to edit (not just suggest edits to) [Community Wiki posts](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki) is significantly lower than [regular posts](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit), this makes sense; *e.g.*, to make it easier for the community to discover malicious edits.)

That said, if the edit is a correction in substance to a post, it is probably a good idea to make it.  While you're at it, check if any other corrections can be made to that post.  (We're not really against bumping old questions, but of bumping larger batches of older question. If all the sudden you bump 5 or 6 old questions in a matter of minutes, other users will undoubtedly take issue with this.)