# Why can't I see my (CW) answers in question list?

Tags: support, frontpage

I've been trying to remove some questions from the unanswered list, often by converting comment-answers to CW answers. To try and avoid flooding the front page, I started checking to see how far down the previous question had got before clicking 'answer'. However, I've realised I can never see the previous one (I have 50 questions showing). I even tried looking at the front page immediately after posting an answer, and refreshing to check I've got the new page. The answer to [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13821/will-an-edit-to-a-community-wiki-bump-the-question) question says a CW post should still bump a question (although technically it refers to edits). Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: If it is not shown on the front page immediately, but it is shown after, say, 2 minutes, the reason might be caching. How long after posting your answer have you checked the front page? (For example, at this moment I see [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/654185/division-algorithm-for-polynomials-condition-on-field) on the front page. I use 50 questions per page, sorted by [recent activity](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=active).)

Comment: Thanks, I've found it - my list was showing newest instead of activity.

Comment: I am glad that the problem was solved. I want also say that I appreciate yours (and anyone's) effort to help with [older unanswered questions](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9141/the-crusade-of-answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [comment by the OP](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17001/why-cant-i-see-my-cw-answers-in-question-list#comment62819_17001) indicates that the problem has been solved, I am posted an answer anyway, so that the question does not remain unanswered.

I can think of two reasons for not seeing question on the frontpage after it was answered:

- This might be caused by [caching](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/caching), if you check the front page immediately after bumping the question. In this case checking again 1-2 minutes later should work.
- You should also make sure that you are viewing the questions sorted by [recent activity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=active) and not by some of the other criteria (newest, votes, frequent, etc.).